# Как решить AttributeError("'Message' object has no attribute 'message'")? tgbot py

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для Телеграмма, и столкнулся с ошибкой :

```
AttributeError("'Message' object has no attribute 'message'")
```

в команде:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
def successful_payment(message: aiogram.types.Message):
    print("SUCCESSFUL PAYMENT:")
    payment_info = successful_payment.to_python()
    for k, v in payment_info.items():
        print(f"{k} = {v}")
    bot.send_message(message.successful_payment.chat.id, f"Платёж на сумму {successful_payment.total_amount // 100} {message.successful_payment.currency} прошел успешно!")
```

Не понимаю в чем проблема, так что прошу вас помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Ваш код должен выглядеть вот так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
def successful_payment(message: aiogram.types.Message):
    print("SUCCESSFUL PAYMENT:")
    payment_info = message.successful_payment.to_python()
    # payment_info = successful_payment.to_python() - БЫЛО
    for k, v in payment_info.items():
        print(f"{k} = {v}")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Платёж на сумму {message.successful_payment.total_amount // 100} {message.successful_payment.currency} прошел успешно!")
```